# How can I split a DNS zone and forward unknown queries?

Tags: dns-zone

This might be a little odd but basically I have a domain that exists on the outside let's call it "deploy.myitcompany.com". This domain is used for deploying iPads for a company using Apple MDM. The issues I running into is inside the building they are using an entirely different domain. Let's call that one "abccompany.com".

I am looking for a way to setup a DNS forward lookup zone (in Windows DNS) and add ONLY the record I care about which would be "deploy.myitcompany.com" BUT if I don't know the entry I want to forward the request to my configured forwarders.

Does this make sense? The issue I run into is if I add "myitcompany.com" to the local DNS server then certain records like "www" and "mail" no longer resolve unless I add the records to the local DNS which I would like to avoid.

Any insight into this?

My original idea was to fix it by changing the entire DNS server to be more simple to work with but this is being met with resistance so I need a workaround.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify a bit on what I meant.

I work as a contractor for a small IT company. The company was working with a client to deploy iPads on their network. The previous guy had setup the Mac server to point to deploy.myitcompany.com instead of the client's domain. The issue I am running into is if I put a domain in their DNS server that includes "myitcompany.com" and add an A record it works as it should. But now if I try to go to "www.myitcompany.com" inside the network it fails since the local DNS does not know where "www" is supposed to go since there is no record. I am able to override this issue by adding a "www" record but that would mean I have to add all of the records for our domain so they work from with in the clients network.

Since the client really owns the equipment what I meant by fixing the entire DNS server was to change everything to what "should" be for the client and in turn not having to add our records to their server. But as I said I am meeting some resistance on this.

I was looking for a way to do a kind of split DNS where the server holds some other records for the domain and anything it does not know how to fulfill I wanted it to pass to the configured forwarders I setup.

Does that make sense?

Comment: If you were using something other then Windows DNS I would suggest response policy zones.  https://dnsrpz.info/

Answer (score 1):

`My original idea was to fix it by changing the entire DNS server to be more simple to work with` - What does that mean, exactly?

`I am looking for a way to setup a DNS forward lookup zone (in Windows DNS) and add ONLY the record I care about which would be "deploy.myitcompany.com"` - I don't quite understand this statement but if you're saying that you want to create a zone named `myitcompany.com` and populate it with an A record named `deploy.myitcompany.com` and have queries for all other names in the `myitcompany.com` domain resolved by the external name servers for the `myitcompany.com` domain then you just need to create a zone named `deploy.myitcompany.com` and add an A record with a blank name for the ip address of deploy.myitcompany.com.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just that simple? Create a new domain in the forward lookup zone and create an A record? I had tried this and it was working, nslookup showed it pointing to the wrong IP address. I'll have to take another look.

Comment: You have to create a zone for the name of the A record that you want to resolve (deploy.myitcomapny.com), not for the parent domain (myitcompany.com). Then create an "empty" A record for the ip address that you want to resolve `deploy.myitcomapny.com` to. Take a close look at my screenshots.